# Python nested-loop speed comparison unexpectedly slower when computing intermediate expression

Tags: python, algorithm, timing

In the case where python executes more operations, it is slower.

The following is a very simple comparison of two separate nested loops (for finding a Pythagorean triple `(a,b,c)` which sum to 1000):

```
#Takes 9 Seconds
for a in range(1, 1000):
  for b in range(a, 1000):
    ab = 1000 - (a + b)
    for c in range(ab, 1000):
      if(((a + b + c) == 1000) and ((a**2) + (b**2) == (c**2))):
        print(a,b,c)
        exit()


#Solution B
#Takes 7 Seconds
for a in range(1, 1000):
  for b in range(a, 1000):
    for c in range(b, 1000):
      if(((a + b + c) == 1000) and ((a**2) + (b**2) == (c**2))):
        print(a,b,c)
        exit()
```

I expected solution A to shave a second or two off of solution B but instead it increased the time it took to complete. by two seconds.

```
instead of iterating
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
...
1, 1, 999
1, 2, 2

It would iterate
1, 1, 998
1, 1, 999
1, 2, 997
1, 2, 998
1, 2, 999
1, 3, 996
```

It seems to me that solution a should vastly improve speed by cutting out thousands to millions of operations, but it in fact does not.

I am aware that there is a simple way to vastly improve this algorithm but I am trying to understand why python would run slower in the case that would seem to be faster.

Comment: This does *not* find all such triples; it finds one triple and aborts.

Comment: Yes, that's a very interesting catch, it should not be ~30% slower. Can you try option C where you directly use `for c in range(1000 - (a + b), 1000):` without storing `ab`?

Comment: @Prune There is only one such triplet according to Project Euler. His phrasing is off.

Comment: @Prune, ok, whatever, I did not see the `exit()` call after the `print()`. Anyway that doesn't change the question at all, this is a good catch.

Comment: FYI this is [Project Euler #9](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just count total amount of iterations in each solution and see that A takes more iterations to find the result:

```
#Takes 9 Seconds
def A():
 count = 0
 for a in range(1, 1000):
  for b in range(a, 1000):
    ab = 1000 - (a + b)
    for c in range(ab, 1000):
      count += 1
      if(((a + b + c) == 1000) and ((a**2) + (b**2) == (c**2))):
        print(a,b,c)
        print('A:', count)
        return


#Solution B
#Takes 7 Seconds
def B():
 count = 0
 for a in range(1, 1000):
  for b in range(a, 1000):
    for c in range(b, 1000):
      count += 1
      if(((a + b + c) == 1000) and ((a**2) + (b**2) == (c**2))):
        print(a,b,c)
        print('B:', count)
        return

A()
B()
```

Output:

```
A: 115425626
B: 81137726
```

That's why A is slower. Also `ab = 1000 - (a + b)` takes time.

Comment: Chalk that one up to bad math on my part. Getting back into coding and I forgot not to trust my own math if things don't add up.

Answer (score 1):

You have two false premises in your confusion:

- The methods find all triples.  They do not; each one finds a single triple and then aborts.
- The upper method (aka "solution A") does fewer comparisons.

I added some basic instrumentation to test your premises:

import time

```
#Takes 9 Seconds
count = 0
start = time.time()
for a in range(1, 1000):
  for b in range(a, 1000):
    ab = 1000 - (a + b)
    for c in range(ab, 1000):
      count += 1
      if(((a + b + c) == 1000) and ((a**2) + (b**2) == (c**2))):
        print(a,b,c)
        print(count, time.time() - start)
        break


#Solution B
#Takes 7 Seconds
count = 0
start = time.time()
for a in range(1, 1000):
  for b in range(a, 1000):
    for c in range(b, 1000):
      count += 1
      if(((a + b + c) == 1000) and ((a**2) + (b**2) == (c**2))):
        print(a,b,c)
        print(count, time.time() - start)
        break
```

Output:

```
200 375 425
115425626 37.674554109573364
200 375 425
81137726 25.986871480941772
```

`Solution B` considers fewer triples.  Do the math ... which is the lower value, `b` or `1000-a-b` for this exercise?

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a performance difference, but because your code is doing different things:

- Solution A runs c over the `range(1000-(a+b), 1000)`, which will be much shorter. (in fact it doesn't need to run c, it only needs to check for one value `c = 1000-(a+b)`, since that's the only c-value for given a,b that satisfies the constraint `(a + b + c) == 1000)`)

  - however it does compute and store `ab = 1000-(a+b)`, which will be stored in the `locals()` dict
- Solution B runs c over the entire `range(b, 1000)`. But it just uses the expression `1000-(a+b)` directly, it doesn't store it to a local variable `ab`.